# Alternative for multifield mapping in Elasticsearch.net v. 2.3+ library (c#)?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

**My problem:**
I have an index with a string property, on which I perform queries and aggregations. I would like to perform terms-queries with that property being analyzed and terms-aggregations with that property being not-analyzed. In previous versions of elasticsearch there was a multifield mapping for that, but it's gone since 2.0 version of that library. How can I achieve that?

**Sidenote:**
I would like to avoid duplicating that property in my index and marking one of duplicates as analyzed and the other one as not-analyzed, because it doesn't seem like efficent solution.

**Libraries I use (c#):** Elasticsearch.net 2.3.3 and NEST 2.3.3.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multi_field` mappings still exist in Elasticsearch 2.x and NEST 2.x; here's an example

```
client.Map<Document>(m => m
    .Index("index-name")
    .AutoMap()
    .Properties(p => p
        .String(s => s
            .Name(n => n.Location)
            .Fields(f => f
                .String(fs => fs
                    .Name("raw").NotAnalyzed()
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Here the `Location` property is mapped as a `multi_field` with the default `Standard` analyzer applied to it; this will be within the `location` field within the index. Additionally, a `location.raw` field has been indexed which is not analyzed.

To perform a term query using the analyzed `location` property would be

```
client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Term(f => f.Location, "location")
    )
);
```

And to use the not analyzed property within a terms aggregation would be

```
client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("top_locations", ta => ta
            .Field(f => f.Location.Suffix("raw"))
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)